# V-model in vue-at is not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vue-at@2.x package https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-at for my vue project.

```
<template>
  <div>
   <at-ta :members="members" v-model="theWholeText">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </at-ta>
  <button @click="aMethod()" >Click</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AtTa from 'vue-at/dist/vue-at-textarea';
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data() {
    return {
      theWholeText: "",
      members: ['Roxie Miles', 'grace.carroll', '小浩'],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    aMethod() {
      console.log('this.theWholeText :', this.theWholeText); 
    }
  },
  components: { AtTa, },
}
</script>
```

The members list is showing as soon as I write @ in the textarea but the text is not updated to the theWholeText variable, it is still empty. Any idea what is wrong with this code, why v-model is not working?

Comment: can you please post the code of component AtTa

Comment: I don't seem to be able to reproduce the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/ko7zr0ok4o

Comment: @AnkitKumarOjha AtTa is an npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-at You may also need to install - npm i -S textarea-caret to make it work, It is mentioned in the package documentation.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Thanks for this code sample. I compared with my code and was using 2.3.2 version of vue-at which was causing issue. When I tried with 2.5.0-beta version which you were using in your code. It worked. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome. Good for you. @shaina.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Can you check with 2.3.2 version just to be sure that v-model is not working with this version and I am not making any other mistake.

Comment: @AnkitKumarOjha Thank you.

Comment: Yes, 2.3.2 seems to ignore the v-model

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the ability to use a model was added in version 2.4.0-beta in [this commit](https://github.com/fritx/vue-at/commit/a910df6e882b4d66bdd9060853bff953cb2cfeff). I am not sure how you were supposed to accomplish this in previous versions, but you could upgrade to the latest version.